# Using requirejs means no more global variables?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

Does using requirejs means I will not be dealing with global variables anymore?

I am starting to implement requirejs in my project. Before using requirejs, I was attaching my custom Backbone Router class to a namespace variable:

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({customStuffInHere});
```

Say that I am now defining it as a "module":

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    return Backbone.Router.extend({customStuffInHere});
});
```

There is no problem with that, as my custom router is in it's own file Router.js. So it follows the convention one module per file.

When I was creating an instance of this router before requirejs, I was just doing:

```
....code....
app.router = new app.Router();
....code....
```

Now I would have to create an entire new file just for this instantiation and include it in the current module?

Am I doing things right?

Edit: I guess my question is how can I have a single router model for all my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the relative path to your JS file without the .js extension.
(Or use a relative path to `baseUrl`)

By nature RequireJS modules are singletons, meaning you will get a reference to the same object in any `define` or `require` call

```
require('./path/to/Router', function () {
  var router = new Router();
}};
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it seems that it is not a singleton. A new router gets instantiated each time...

Comment: Ahh, never mind, you are right! I did a global.js and store all the global variables in this module. Cheers!